# Not getting output in case of string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s[0] = 'a';
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I used this code and ran, but no output is coming don't know why?

But if am using s = ""; then also no output.

But when I use s = " "; then output comes why does this happen?

Comment: `s[0] = 'a';`  is undefined behavior. You can't access positions of the string that don't exist. `s` is empty when this is called so `s[0]` is out of bounds.

Comment: ***But when I use s = " "; then output comes why does this happen?*** Because in this case then s has a length of 1 instead of 0. With a length of 1, `s[0]` would be a valid operation. The clear point here for you to remember that accessing out of bounds indices does not expand the string and that doing so is undefined behavior / breaking the rules of the language.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized `string`, so assigning `a` to `s[0]` does nothing or does undefined behavior. To do this, you have to give `s` a size, as the options below:

Option 1: Resize

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s.resize(10);
    s[0] = 'a';
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Option 2: Push Back

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s.push_back('a');
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Option 3: +=

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    s += 'a';
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are more options, but I won't put them here. (one might be `append`)

Answer (score 0):

See the notes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) you are trying to access the first (zeroth) character in a string without any characters. This is undefined behavior.